# FOSUserBundle - No route found for "GET /login/"

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, routes, fosuserbundle

I am working with FOSUserBundle and I encounter an error that I can not correct.
 (I use Symfony 3.2.9)

I guess it comes from my security.yml file but I can not find what makes my route bug.

This may be just a detail but I use nginx, and my local url is: 127.0.0.1:83/app_dev.php/.

Only my /login route doesn't work.

**My url is `/login`, but it redirect me to `/login/`**

And i got : `No route found for "GET /login/" (from "http://127.0.0.1:83/app_dev.php/")`

Here is my security.yml file :

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy: ~

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/admin/, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

My config.yml (fosuserbundle config) :

```
# FOSUser Configuration
fos_user:
    db_driver: orm 
    from_email: 
        address: my@email.fr
        sender_name: Admin
    firewall_name: main
    user_class: ProjectBundle\Entity\User\User
    registration:
        form:
            type: ProjectBundle\Form\RegistrationType
```

And `php bin/console debug:router` :

```
  admin_user_index                     ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/user/                                           
  admin_user_show                      ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/user/{id}/show                                  
  admin_user_edit                      ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/user/{id}/edit                                  
  admin_user_new                       ANY        ANY      ANY    /admin/user/create                                     
  home                                 ANY        ANY      ANY    /                                                      
  lexik_translation_overview           GET        ANY      ANY    /admin/translations/                                   
  lexik_translation_grid               GET        ANY      ANY    /admin/translations/grid                               
  lexik_translation_new                GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /admin/translations/new                                
  lexik_translation_invalidate_cache   GET        ANY      ANY    /admin/translations/invalidate-cache                   
  lexik_translation_list               GET        ANY      ANY    /admin/translations/api/translations                   
  lexik_translation_profiler           GET        ANY      ANY    /admin/translations/api/translations/profiler/{token}  
  lexik_translation_update             PUT        ANY      ANY    /admin/translations/api/translations/{id}              
  lexik_translation_delete_locale      DELETE     ANY      ANY    /admin/translations/api/translations/{id}/{locale}     
  lexik_translation_delete             DELETE     ANY      ANY    /admin/translations/api/translations/{id}              
  fos_user_security_login              GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /login                                                 
  fos_user_security_check              POST       ANY      ANY    /login_check                                           
  fos_user_security_logout             GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /logout                                                
  fos_user_registration_register       GET|POST   ANY      ANY    /register/                                             
  fos_user_registration_check_email    GET        ANY      ANY    /register/check-email                                  
  fos_user_registration_confirm        GET        ANY      ANY    /register/confirm/{token}                              
  fos_user_registration_confirmed      GET        ANY      ANY    /register/confirmed
```

**EDIT : More informations**

My routing.yml :

```
project:
    resource: "@ProjectBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"
```

The routing.xml of the login path : [FOSUserBundle Routing File](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/routing/security.xml)

Maybe my problem comes from my Nginx configuration (this is the first I use it) :

```
server {
  listen 83 default_server;
    listen [::]:83 default_server;

  server_name localhost;

  root /var/www/html/MyProject/web;

  access_log            /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log             /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  location / {

    try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
  }
  location ~ ^/(app|app_dev|app_test|config)\.php(/|$) {

    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;

    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  }

}
```

Would anyone have an idea? I'm really stuck in my project.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony set up looks good. I repeated it local. Works for apache2 and nginx as well.
I would suggest to play with nginx config file. Location section looks suspicious.

Comment: Oh okay. I have never used nginx, this is my first time :S.
Can you give me your configuration?

Comment: This is from my project and works fine

security.yml: https://code.re/aj8
config.yml: https://code.re/aj9
routing.yml: https://code.re/aja

Comment: Thank you !  I test it tomorrow and tell you what it gives :)

Comment: Now i've an ngninx error : 
`2017/06/01 09:06:52 [error] 20028#20028: *4 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream, client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request: "GET /app_dev.php/fr/admin/organisations/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:83", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:83/app_dev.php/fr/admin/organisations/1/edit"`


Can you give me your nginx config ?

Comment: I have just default one. I did not change anything.
Here you go: https://code.re/ajf

Comment: Your configuration is completely different from mine :/

I have created a new question so as not to be off topic in relation to the original question.

[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44301644/symfony-nginx-configuration-error-fastcgi-sent-in-stderr-primary-script-unk

Comment: Ok. Just try default apache or default nginx to make sure it is a problem

Comment: The use of nginx is mandatory :S. You think that I should not use the config which is given in the documentation of Symfony?

Comment: Well at least you can try. I have used default one.

Answer (score 0):

```
No route found for "GET /login/"
```

means that the route doesn't exist and is correct, if you look to your `php bin/console debug:router`  you can see that the route is `/login` not `/login/`, remove the last slash please

Comment: I know, i use `{{ url('fos_user_security_login') }}` to generate my route, and it's /login. But when i go to this url, this refers me to / login /

Comment: Have you some file like routing.xml o yml with some fosueser configuration?

Comment: In my routing.yml, i have only : 
`project:
    resource: "@ProjectBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

fos_user:
    resource: "@FOSUserBundle/Resources/config/routing/all.xml"`

Comment: And the routing file for the login route is : 
[https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/routing/security.xml