# Symfony - Nginx Configuration error : FastCGI sent in stderr "Primary script unknown"

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, configuration, server

This is the first time I use nginx with Symfony, and I used the configuration that is on the Symfony document. I have the basic configuration of the latest version of nginx.

However, on my url: 127.0.0.1:83/app_dev.php/fr/admin/organisations

I get the error in my nginx project_error.log file :

```
2017/06/01 09:16:14 [error] 20204#20204:
 *1 FastCGI sent in stderr: "Primary script unknown" while reading response header from upstream,
 client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, 
request: "GET /app_dev.php/fr/admin/organisations/ HTTP/1.1", 
upstream: "fastcgi://unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock:", host: "127.0.0.1:83",
referrer: "http://127.0.0.1:83/app_dev.php/fr/admin/organisations/1/edit"
```

My nginx server config (From Symfony documentation) :

```
server {

listen 83 default_server;
    listen [::]:83 default_server;
    server_name localhost;
    root /var/www/SymfonySkeleton/web;

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to app.php
        try_files $uri /app.php$is_args$args;
    }
    # DEV
    # This rule should only be placed on your development environment
    # In production, don't include this and don't deploy app_dev.php or config.php
    location ~ ^/(app_dev|config)\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
    }
    # PROD
    location ~ ^/app\.php(/|$) {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.*)$;
        include fastcgi_params;
        # When you are using symlinks to link the document root to the
        # current version of your application, you should pass the real
        # application path instead of the path to the symlink to PHP
        # FPM.
        # Otherwise, PHP's OPcache may not properly detect changes to
        # your PHP files (see https://github.com/zendtech/ZendOptimizerPlus/issues/126
        # for more information).
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;
        # Prevents URIs that include the front controller. This will 404:
        # http://domain.tld/app.php/some-path
        # Remove the internal directive to allow URIs like this
        internal;
    }

    # return 404 for all other php files not matching the front controller
    # this prevents access to other php files you don't want to be accessible.
    location ~ \.php$ {
        return 404;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/project_error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/project_access.log;
}
```

Any ideas ? I strongly assume that my configuration is not good

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the lines:

```
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
```

Though this may impact on the use of symlinks in your project. It will remove that error message though.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the **root** path and the files under it .